# node.js program hangs on Amazon linux server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an ubuntu server on Amazon and I'm trying to run a node.js program on it. The program has only one line:

```
console.log('Here I am.');
```

Nothing gets output and program does not exit.

when I run ps x, I can see one [node] process in STAT D state:

```
  751 ?        D      0:04 [node]
```

The process cannot be stopped with sudo kill -9 751.

Before the problem, the node.js program ran just fine, as did my actual - much more elaborate - node.js program.

I even rebooted the ubuntu server and tried running the one-line test node.js program right after reboot. It hung and did not output anything.

node --version returns

```
v0.7.6-pre
```

Any ideas why this happens? Is this a problem related to the Amazon instance, node.js installation or something else? nginx runs just fine on the same server but node.js programs hang as described above.

(as expected, the same code runs just fine on my local mac os x environment)

UPDATE: I reverted back to 0.6.12 stable version but the same problem persists.

Comment: Usually status D means IO, in which it's transit into kernel call. This may explain why you cannot kill it. To help diagnose the problem, try redirect the stdout to a file (using '>'). I suspect the problem may be with outputting to the console/screen. Also try with v0.6 stable release.

Comment: tried both of those (redirecting output and reverted first back to 0.7.5 and then to 0.6.12) but the same problem persists. When the hanged node program is running, top shows node and rsyslogd taking up 100% of one CPU. Occasionally jbd2/xvda1-8 is also on top list with high CPU usage.

Comment: The test program *did* run one time correctly after I installed 0.6.12. On the second run it hung up.

Comment: I have flagged this question to be migrated to [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved (kinda).

This is a mystery. I created a new instance on Amazon EC2 ("identical" to the one I had), installed git, nginx, node.js and my node.js program. Everything works correctly now.

It must be that there was something wrong with the instance I had. I just don't understand what it was but since the instance I had had nothing important on it, I just dumped it.

It could be that the cause for the problem was the 0.7.6-pre version I had initially pulled and compiled. Maybe there were some left-overs from that installation that caused the peculiar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Just for anybody else who comes across this problem, it could be related to this:

["After using yum to upgrade to Amazon Linux AMI 2011.09, t1.micro 32-bit instances fail to reboot."](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2011.09-release-notes/)

Updating the 'AKI' on my instance seemed to fix the problem for me.